# Are there more specific Unicode clock symbols besides these 24 ones?

Tags: unicode

https://www.alt-codes.net/clock-symbols

There is one Unicode symbol for 12 o'clock, half past 12, 1 o'clock, half past 1, etc.

But there are none for "quarter over 12", or "five over 12", etc.?

I tried to make a visual clock but it can currently only show a "precision" of 30 minutes due to the (apparently) limited Unicode symbols.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look likely.
The clock symbols are all consecutive numbers, U+1F550 to U+1F567. The next after twelve thirty is 'right speaker' U+1F568.

My Character Viewer will find items by name even if I don't have an associated font glyph. This is what it finds [including one highlighted that I don't have the glyph for]. Many of them are included in the search because the name contains 'clock' eg 'clockwise', so it should cover all possibles in the Unicode set.

[image]